# Route is listed by rake, but server returns 404 from jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can't quite figure out what's going wrong. This was working earlier today and this afternoon it's stuffed.

I have a jQuery.post() call to a particular URL `/shows/purchase`. When I did a `rake routes` that particular route is listed. However, the jQuery call to http://domain.dev/shows/purchase returns a 404.

Being a Rails newbie (using 3.1) I am not sure where to start looking. Can someone please point me in the right direction so I can start troubleshooting what's going wrong?

Thanks,
Dany.

EDIT: Here are the relevant bit of `rake routes` and `routes.rb`

```
shows_purchase POST   /shows/purchase(.:format)              {:controller=>"shows", :action=>"purchase"}
```

and

```
post "shows/purchase"
resources :shows
```

Comment: How about the `jQuery.post()` call? Does `ShowsController#purchase` get called? Anything interesting in the Rails logs?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of the logs! As it turned out there was a problem in the after_save callback within the entity's parent model (if that's the right jargon). Without the logs I would never have guessed it caused a 404! How do I credit you for the useful prompt? Is upvoting the comment enough?

Comment: You can pay it forward and help someone else :) I'm happy if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out there was an error within the model's `after_save` callback during the `save` call. For some crazy reason it raises a 404! I only found out by delving into development.log as suggested in the comments above.